# There is any way to do multi selection in pickerview?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to set multiple selection for my pickerview does it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that with UIPickerView (anyway - selected item is always positioned on central row - it has to be the only one at least for that reason). You can make UIPickerView with multiple sections(columns) though and each section will have 1 selected item if that suit you.

The best option for multiple selection (imo) is UITableView with `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` accessory view